# Fancybox - Set width without stretching image

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

I have a gallery with images and description text.

Some of the images are short and wide, which display fine, but the tall narrow images all display the text in the same width as the image underneath. Like this:

[image]

I want to be able to have the whole box set as a minimum width of 800px, but not have the image try and strech to this size. The image must stay at the same size, and float in the middle.

using minWidth / Width / Height all don't display this correctly, and all of them focus on the image size, not the box size.

The only way around it I can think of at the moment would be to add white space to the narrow images.

Comment: did you try width="100%" or min-width="100%"

Comment: Tried this:.fancybox-image{
 margin:0 auto !important;
}
.fancybox-skin{
 min-width:800px;
} but the image is to the left, the box is no longer centered on the page